# Templating based on Nunjucks with live preview and export capabilities for non coders - Open source solutions?

Tags: templates, documentation-generation, nunjucks

I am looking for an opensource solution to make templates documents based on Nunjucks inputs that can be exported to other format like PDG, Word etc.If a live preview capability is available thats even better. This open sources sources solution should be non coder friendly.
Do you have some recommendations?

The closest I found is Mozilla wedmaker but it s not maintained anymore.
I also looked at Overleaf but that requires to understand markdown too much.
Corbone.io seems an interesting solution but it does not support advances formating, there is no autocomplete and its not based nunjuck

Thank you